# PDO query in Slim causes PHP Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Unexpected data in output buffer

Tags: php, pdo, slim

So my basic slim app goes along these lines:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!file_exists( __DIR__ . '/settings.php')) { die("Error 500: application configuration problem."); }
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$config = require __DIR__ . '/settings.php';
$app = new \Slim\App($config);

$container = $app->getContainer();

$container['s4s'] = function ($container) {
    $db = $container['settings']['s4s'];
    return new PDO('sqlsrv:Server='.$db['host'].';Database='.$db['database'], $db['username'], $db['password']);
};

$app->get('/ff', function ($request, $response) {

        $sql = 'SELECT "dbo"."ZAKAZKA"."ZAKAZKA ID" FROM "dbo"."ZAKAZKA" WHERE ("ZAKAZKA ID" LIKE \'1216%\' ) ORDER BY "dbo"."ZAKAZKA"."ZAKAZKA ID"  DESC';
        $stmt = $this->s4s->prepare($sql);

        if($stmt->execute()){
            echo $stmt->debugDumpParams();
            $results=$stmt->fetchAll();
        }

  });
```

this works fine and dandy. If I move the query code to a controller

```
<?php

namespace Glued\Playground;
use \PDO;
use Glued\Controllers\Controller;


class pdo_test extends Controller
{
    public function test($request, $response)
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT "dbo"."ZAKAZKA"."ZAKAZKA ID" FROM "dbo"."ZAKAZKA" WHERE ("ZAKAZKA ID" LIKE \'1216%\' ) ORDER BY "dbo"."ZAKAZKA"."ZAKAZKA ID"  DESC';
        echo $sql;
        $stmt = $this->container->s4s->prepare($sql); // this line breaks things
        if($stmt->execute()){
            echo $stmt->debugDumpParams();
            $results=$stmt->fetchAll();
        }

    }    
}
```

and add to the main code

```
$app->get('/playground/fff', '\Glued\Playground\Pdo_test::mytest');
```

it starts to break at the $stmt assignment with the error

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Unexpected data in output buffer. Maybe you have characters before an opening finalize(Object(Slim\Http\Response))\n#1 /opt/Web/html/glued/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(298): Slim\App->process(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))\n#2 /opt/Web/html/glued/public/index.php(4): Slim\App->run()\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in /opt/Web/html/glued/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php on line 552

since this doesnt apply to other controllers I wrote sofar, I'm either overlooking something obvious or PDO (which I dont usually use) causes the premature output. Not sure how to debug this as well.

Hints and solutions very welcome, thanks in advance!

note: I usually dont work with mssql as well, but I got the same problem against a mysql db.

Comment: your using `"` instead of `\`` back ticks in your query.

Comment: @cmorrissey Backticks are for MySQL, he's using SQL-Server.

Comment: The error is probably because of `echo $stmt->debugDumpParams();` Why are you doing that?

Comment: @Barmar - i dont even get to the debugDumpParams(). The script starts to fail at $stmt = $this->container->s4s->prepare($sql);